tokio::task::spawn and non-Send objects in async context
I am struggling to wrap my head around Send and the async context. At present, I am interacting with solana-sdk which has a Signature object which does not implement Send. I interact with this library in an async context in new tasks spawned in tokio.
To illustrate the problem outside of the context of the SDK, I have the following minimum reproducible code:
#![feature(negative_impls)]

use std::sync::Arc;
use tokio::sync::Mutex;

// Library Code
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

struct GoofyProperty {}
impl !Send for GoofyProperty {}
impl !Sync for GoofyProperty {}

struct GoofyBuilder { pub prop: GoofyProperty }
// This guy is also !Send and !Sync, implicitly
impl GoofyBuilder {
    pub fn new() -> Self { Self { prop: GoofyProperty {} } }
    pub fn x(&mut self) -> &mut Self { /* Do some "building". */ self }
    pub fn y(&mut self) -> &mut Self { /* Do some "building". */ self }
    pub async fn do_some_request(&self) { /* Perform some API call */ }
}

struct GoofyProgram { }
// Implicitly...
// impl Send for GoofyProgram {};
// impl Sync for GoofyProgram {};
impl GoofyProgram {
    pub fn builder(&self) -> GoofyBuilder { GoofyBuilder::new() }
}

// My Code
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
struct SomeStatefulManager {}
impl SomeStatefulManager {
    pub async fn service(&mut self) {
        let my_program = GoofyProgram{};
        my_program.builder()
            .x()
            .y()
            .do_some_request().await
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let my_managers = vec![
        Arc::new(Mutex::new(SomeStatefulManager{})),
        Arc::new(Mutex::new(SomeStatefulManager{})),
    ];

    let mut my_futures = vec![];

    for manager in my_managers {
        let manager_rc = manager.clone();

        my_futures.push(tokio::task::spawn(async move {
            let mut man = manager_rc.lock().await;

            man.service().await;
        }));
    }
}

The compiler complains:
error: future cannot be sent between threads safely
   --> src/main.rs:62:25
    |
62  |           my_futures.push(tokio::task::spawn(async move {
    |  _________________________^
63  | |             let mut man = manager_rc.lock().await;
64  | |
65  | |             man.service().await;
66  | |         }));
    | |__________^ future created by async block is not `Send`
    |
    = help: within `{async block@src/main.rs:62:44: 66:10}`, the trait `Send` is not implemented for `GoofyProperty`, which is required by `{async block@src/main.rs:62:44: 66:10}: Send`
note: future is not `Send` as this value is used across an await
   --> src/main.rs:46:32
    |
43  |         my_program.builder()
    |         -------------------- has type `GoofyBuilder` which is not `Send`
...
46  |             .do_some_request().await
    |                                ^^^^^ await occurs here, with `my_program.builder()` maybe used later

Note how GoofyProperty is explicitly marked as !Send and !Sync. This effectively means that, at the await point in SomeStatefulManager::service, my_program.builder() cannot be shared between objects.
It is clear to me that the await point requires synchronization. I, however, do not understand how to approach this problem -- my_program.builder() is a temporary object. If I were to wrap it in a Mutex, all I would do is have a MutexGuard which also isn't Sync.
Thanks for the help!

I believe you're out of luck. Why do you need spawn()?

But Signature does implement Send.

You should probably look into kmdreko's comment first, but for your information you can spawn tasks that do not require Send with spawn_local.
As always with rust though, freedom of type means restriction of operations, so this may require some rethinking of the architecture
